# Why is my linkExtractor in a scrapy spider semming to not crawl allowed links?

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have created a simple spider to scrape `disneyfoodblog.com` posts and return the post title and post permalink.

My project does not show any errors. Debug output (see below) reveals that all starting links are visited, but no links on those pages are being crawled. The start pages are the pages that house each day's posts. From there, I am trying to crawl the actual post.

- Here is an example of a start link: http://www.disneyfoodblog.com/2014/12/31/
- Here is a post: http://www.disneyfoodblog.com/2014/12/31/photo-tour-and-review-new-polynesian-village-resort-lobby-and-tiramisu-cupcake-at-captain-cooks-in-disneys-polynesian-village-resort/

My spider code:

```
import datetime

import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule 
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy import log

from dfbScrape.items import *


class dfbSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name="dfb"
    base="http://disneyfoodblog.com/"
    allowed_domains=[base]

    start_urls=[]
    startDate=datetime.date(2014,6,1)
    endDate=datetime.date.today()
    while startDate<endDate:
        start_urls.append(base+str(startDate.year)+"/"+startDate.strftime("%m")+"/"+startDate.strftime("%d")+"/")
        startDate+=datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=["\d+/\d+/\d+/.+/"]), callback='parse_item')]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.log('Hi, this is an item page! %s' % response.url)
        item =DfbscrapeItem()
        item['title']=response.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/main/article/header/h1').extract()
        item['link']=response.url
        print "t: %s l: %s" % (item['title'],item['link'])
        return item
```

Debug output can be viewed on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=yKsvN9Y9).

Let me know if I should include the actual output here. I didn't because it is almost 800 lines long.

The only idea I have is IMHO not a very good one. It could be a problem with the deprecated link extractor. I picked this over lxml because I found no examples using lxml and a quite a bit using the old one. Even if you can't answer my question, lxml advantages and examples are much appreciated. As always constructive criticism and edits are welcome. Please ask for any additional information you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the output more closely, you would see the "Filtered offsite request" messages:

> 2015-06-07 10:00:01-0500 [dfb] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to
>   'www.disneyfoodblog.com': http://www.disneyfoodblog.com/2013/03/26/best-disney-world-restaurants-for-first-time-disney-visitors/>

Which means that the "Link Extractor" does it's job.

But, your `allowed_domains` setting is not defined correctly, should be defined as:

```
allowed_domains = ["www.disneyfoodblog.com"]
```

(Worked for me).

Comment: Whoops! I didn't catch that. Sorry. Quite a weird issue nonetheless.